# Linq create typed result list

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have made some hard work, I think may be there is library that can make this work. For example, I create a model classes for .NET EF 6 mapped to Sql Server tables:

```
class Author {
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Book {
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public long AuthorId { get; set;}
}
```

there is iherited class:

```
class BookEx : Book {
   public string AuthorName { get;set; }
}
```

and LINQ query:

```
   var query = from t in context.Books
      join t1 in context.Authors on t.Id equals t1.AuthorId
      select new BookEx {
         Id = t.Id,
         Name = t.Name,
         AuthorId = t.AuthorId,
         AuthorName = t1.Name
      }
```

every thinks works fine, but this is simple class, when I need class like Book with more properies, I need fill every properties and it is too hard some times:

```
  select new BookEx {
     Id = t.Id,
     Name = t.Name,
     AuthorId = t.AuthorId,
     AuthorName = t1.Name
  }
```

can I make a short version of filling like:

```
  select new BookEx {
     AuthorName = t1.Name
  }
```

where properties of parent class Book will filled by LINQ or some other methods? Is there libraries that can make this hard work (some times we forget fill some properties)?

**EDITED:** Project don't use associations. There is no need to use association, take full table (in table can be 10-40 properties) data of Author but get only Name property. Need solve problem like in exmple.

Comment: Properties of Child can be directly mapped to Parent when you do like Parent p = childClassObject. But it's not the same other way round. To map parent to child (or any set of objects with similar properties) have a look at AutoMapper http://automapper.org/

Comment: Yes, it is. I cannot remember how was named that library. If I understand, library use reflection, but what perfomance is this lib? Can you please write useage example for LINQ?

Comment: Yes it uses reflection, but it does that only once and create a mapping. Then it uses the same mapping whenever you try to map. But on the other hand, overall what you are trying to achieve, is very much doable by EF itself. If you already hav the database created, use EF data-first, let it create the objects & fetch the book with author and other details. If you have modeled your objects, let EF create the db schema for you.

Comment: I use model-first, but I can't use associations, we need more perfomance of application, as it can be, it is very important for our customer. I think there is no need to create a model for Author in Book with 10-40 properties to get only name to display. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to create a new entity named BookEx, you can access Author entity details like AuthorName using navigation properties. You don't need to use select statement. For example:

```
 var books = from t in context.Books
      join t1 in context.Authors on t.Id equals t1.AuthorId;
```

this will return Book details with Author detials too so you can get the AuthorName like this-

```
foreach(var item in books)
{
    string authorName=item.Author.Name;
}

To achieve this you need to add one more property (navigation property to Author) in your book class:

public class Book {
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public long AuthorId { get; set;}
   public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this solution, but project not use associations. I need solve problem like in example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a paramount concern you may have to lose some flexibility, but you shouldn't sacrifice re-use.  It's unclear where your break-even is here, but if your approach of creating a `BookEx` projection is working for you, you can certainly wrap it in a method for re-use.  This way you avoid "needing to fill every property" and "sometimes...forgetting to fill some properties":

```
static class DaoExtensions 
{
  public static IQueryable<BookEx> BookPlusAuthorNames(this DbContext context) 
  {
    var query = from t in context.Books
      join t1 in context.Authors on t.Id equals t1.AuthorId
      select new BookEx {
         Id = t.Id,
         Name = t.Name,
         AuthorId = t.AuthorId,
         AuthorName = t1.Name
      }
    return query;
  }        
}
```

Again, because of your performance concern, I wouldn't go to an external library for this problem as stated.

---

For posterity: if development flexibility were prioritized over performance, it would be better to map this natural association by adding `Author` as a navigation property on `Book`:

```
class Book {
    ...
    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow usage like `book.Author.Name` to navigate directly to `Name`.  EF will handle all the join-logic.

Comment: Yes, I know this solution, but project not use associations. I need solve problem like in example. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, your limitations weren't clear in your original question. It appeared as though you were approaching this problem as a "newbie".  You should edit your question to include the points made in your comments, and I'll set about modifying my answer.